# How to delete an acl from dm_acl object table

Tags: dql, documentum, dfc

I am using documentum and I want to remove few acls from my dm_acl object table . first I made sure that the acl exists :

```
select * from dm_acl where object_name = 'myAclName'
```

then I made sure that no other object is using that acl

```
select * from dm_folder where acl_name = 'myAclName'
```

and then I used the following to delete that acl :

```
delete dm_acl objects where object_name = 'myAclName'
```

But then I receive an error saying that `you have specified a none updatable type (dm_acl)`. Is there any way that I can delete an acl using either `DQL` or `DFC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete ACL objects using DQL. However you can delete it using API with syntax

```
destroy,c,<acl_object_id>
```

One more thing, check you mentioned

```
select * from dm_folder where acl_name = 'myAclName'
```

is not enough. ACL object can be found on every sysobject so basically you need to widen your check to dm_sysobject type

```
select * from dm_sysobject where acl_name = 'myAclName'
```

Deleting ACL through DFC is possible since there is destroyACL() method on IDfAcl interface.

Comment: I see , but how can I actually use such `APIs` like the one you mentioned above in java ? any link , resource or even a sample is appreciated  :) I tried to google it but couldn't find any reasonable result

Comment: You can run it in Documentum Administrator or download Repoint or DqMan to use it when you play with it. You can run it dirrectly on Content Server if you need to run it once, using command line tools. You can run it within DFC code but in this case its easier to use IDfAcl objects and call ddestroyACL() method.